# AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2

I keep seeing this error in my apache log when someone visits the shop page on my site, I have tried removing my htaccess and using .php?s=$var and I still get the same error so I think its something to do with the apache config files and not anything to do with the htaccess file, here it is anyway

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^home/?$ home.php  [NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /shop\?c=([^&\s]+)&s=([^&\s]+)&s2=([^&\s]+)&b=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ shop/%1/%2/%3/%4? [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^shop/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ shop.php?c=$1&s=$2&s2=$3&b=$4 [L,QSA,B]
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ shop.php?c=$1&s=$2&s2=$3 [L,QSA,B]
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ shop.php?c=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

SSL apache conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

HTTP apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/example.com">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What is the requested URL that triggers the rewrite loop? You should enable mod_rewrite debugging in the server config (eg. `LogLevel rewrite:trace3` or similar) to get the backtrace from the rewrite loop - this will give a big clue as to what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the server config files you've posted that would result in a rewrite loop - there are *no* rewrites in your server config.

> I have tried removing my htaccess and using `.php?s=$var` and I still get the same error

That is puzzling. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? Without any `.htaccess` files and with the server config you've posted it would seem to be impossible to get a rewrite loop - since you would have no rewrites at all!

However, your last rule block that appends the `.php` extension could result in a rewrite loop under certain conditions. This needs to be corrected. You currently have:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
> ```

The problem with this is that the 2nd condition that checks to see that `<filename>.php` exists, is not necessarily performing the same file check that the following `RewriteRule` would rewrite to. eg. Request `/foo/bar`, where `/foo.php` exists, would result in a rewrite loop.

To resolve this issue, you would need to change the 2nd condition to something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
```

See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the following ServerFault question that explains this in more detail:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

So, the complete rule becomes:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

You should also ensure that MultiViews is disabled (if not already), since your URLs map directly to files less the `.php` file extension (otherwise mod_negotiation will rewrite the URL - before mod_rewrite - and you will lose the URL parameters). At the top of your `.htaccess` file include:

```
Options -MultiViews
```